# jQuery is not a function

Tags: jquery, joomla1.5

I am trying to install a simple news ticker jQuery plugin to the home page of a website built using Joomla 1.5

No matter what I do, I always get the error `jQuery("#js-news").ticker is not a function` despite the files are loaded correctly and the `$` sign is replaced with `jQuery` to avoid conflicts with Mootools.

I also tried to use the Cycle plugin first, but I was getting the same error. The weird thing is I am using the jQuery library (1.6.2) without any problem.

link [here](http://beta.sportingaffair.co.uk/)

Any suggestion?

Thanks

Comment: Is the jQuery script file included before this line of code is called?

Comment: I did some stepping through with Firebug and it looks like the plugin is creating itself correctly in the `jQuery1.6.2` library that you have on the page, however there is also a `jQuery1.2.6` library there too. If you do `jQuery()` or `$()` to create an empty object in the console you will see it uses the `1.2.6` version. So the plugin doesn't exist in that context.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would try to wrap it in a `document.ready()` as well - defining jQuery last is perfect but remember to call `noConflict()`. Consider the following :

```
$j = jQuery.noConflict();

$j(document).ready(function(){
    $j('#js-news').ticker();
});
```

Or alternatively - Thanks @Kevin B

```
$j = jQuery.noConflict();

$j(document).ready(function($){
    $('#js-news').ticker();
});
```

Comment: Bingo! It works, the solutions proposed by David and swatkins did not. Thanks!

Comment: @f0x You could also make it easier to manage with `$j(document).ready(function($){ /* i can use $ in here now */ });`.

Answer (score 1):

Try adding this to your first line of code:

```
jQuery.noConflict();
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks to me as if you need to use `$.noConflict();` ( http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.noConflict/ )

I get the error with the `jQuery` or `$` on your page, unless I execute the `noConflict` method. It seems the ticker plugin is not executing because of the mootools conflict.